# Relations involving Fibonacci and Lucas numbers $F_{mn}, F_n, L_n$

Tags: reference-request, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

If we take $\alpha = \frac {1 + \sqrt 5} 2$ and $\beta = \frac {1 - \sqrt 5} 2$ and $F_n$ be the $n$-th Fibonacci number and $L_n$ be the companion Lucas number then,

$$
F_n = \frac {\alpha^n - \beta^n} {\alpha - \beta} \text{ and } L_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n \text{ for $n = 1, 2, \cdots$ }. \tag 1
$$

We also have

$$
F_{2n} = F_n L_n \text{ and } L_n^2 - 5F_n^2 = 4(-1)^n \tag 2
$$

This gives a relation between the $n$-th Fibonacci/Lucas numbers and $F_{2n}$.

If we replaced $2$ with $m$ in the LHS of Eqn. (2), are there known relations for $F_{mn}$ in terms of the $m$-th, $n$-th Fibonacci/Lucas numbers? Please provide reeferences.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076051/show-that-f-3n-f-nl-2n-1n gives one example of what you want.

Comment: See under *Transformations: multiple arguments* at https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Fibonacci/introductions/FibonacciLucasNumbers/ShowAll.html

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson. There are a whole bunch of relations of the form that I requested. If you would want to put that as an answer, I can upvote/accept it.

Comment: OK, I've done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Fibonacci/introductions/FibonacciLucasNumbers/ShowAll.html under *Transformations: multiple arguments* we find several such formulas, e.g.,
$$
F_{mn}=L_mF_{m(n-1)}-(-1)^mF_{m(n-2)}
$$